# jQuery Nivo Slider: get a wrong value by direct access to the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

i use Nivo-Slider for a little Slideshow whith 6 Pictures:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    $('#image-slider').nivoSlider({                             
        beforeChange: function(){

            var test = $('#image-slider').data('nivo:vars');
            console.log(test);
            console.log(test.currentSlide);                 

        },          
    });
});
```

The Output of console.log(test) shows this:

```
({currentSlide:1, currentImage:{0:{}, context:{}, length:1}, totalSlides:6, running:true, paused:false, stop:false, controlNavEl:{0:{}, length:1}})
```

I need the value of currentSlide, so i try to get it with:

```
var cs = test.currentSlide;
```

But the values im getting on this way differs from the values that shows by

```
 console.log(test)
```

`console.log(test)` shows me the wantet values from 0 to 5, which i need to knowing the next Picture in Slide. The values getting by `test.currentSlide` are most one less, but if i use the Direction-Navigation and hit "Back", it even goes negative to -3 and jump after then to 3 etc. - useless.

How i can get the value of currentSlide which is listet in the output of `console.log(test)`?